# Front Door end to end TLS and app service custom domains

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have an app service protected by Front Door. App Service access restrictions only allow connections from FrontDoor.

App service accepts https only TLS1.2.. FD routing set to httpsOnly.

Let's Encrypt TLS Cert is setup in keyvault and custom domain setup in Frontdoor.

The backend host header field in FD is left empty, to allow for custom domain to be passed in header to app service to avoid broken redirects and cookies (redirects were going to app service DNS instead of FD)

I added the custom domains to app service.. but getting a warning that there are no TLS bindings.

Do I need them, given I don't allow connections direct to app service but to FD only?

The FrontDoor TLS end to end encryption documentation states the
following:

> For HTTPS connections, Azure Front Door expects that your
> backend presents a certificate from a valid Certificate Authority (CA)
> with subject name(s) matching the backend hostname. As an example, if
> your backend hostname is set to myapp-centralus.contosonews.net and
> the certificate that your backend presents during the TLS handshake
> doesn't have myapp-centralus.contosonews.net or *.contosonews.net in
> the subject name, then Azure Front Door will refuse the connection and
> as a result an error.

My understanding here is FD relies on the app service hostname and TLS cert (Azure managed) to encrypt its backend connection.

Everything works, and I don't see any security warnings in the browser... but wondering if in fact the backend TLS encryption is being correctly implemented?